# Show Normal Number Instead of Exponential Form

Tags: android, double, normalization, bigdecimal, primitive-types

I want to show number in a Normal form instead of Exponential Form

For Example My Number is stored in a double variable with value 1234567890123

I want to get the exact representation. but when I pass it to some TextView for display, it becomes 1.234E12

Answer (score 5):

Try Out with the Big decimal class in java..

Big decimal class has the advantage of some inbuilt Rounding function which you can use for example:

```
Double a = 7.77d * 100000000; //Multiply Operation

System.out.println("Large multiply " + a.doubleValue());

System.out.println("Magic of big decimal " + BigDecimal.valueOf(a).setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());

a = 7.77d / 100000; //Devide Operation

System.out.println("Devide operation " + a.doubleValue());

System.out.println("Magic of big decimal " + BigDecimal.valueOf(a).toPlainString());

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");

System.out.println("Trimming the big string : "+formatter .format(a));
```

Output :

```
Large multiply 7.77E8

Magic of big decimal 777000000

Devide operation 7.769999999999999E-5

Magic of big decimal 0.00007769999999999999

Trimming the big string : 0.000078
```

Comment: The link you provided is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
double v = 1234567890123d;
Double d = new Double( v );
```

Now when you pass it to TextView, you can pass it as follows (assuming that you are interested only in the integer part of a `double`):

```
d.longValue();
```

Now, why is it giving you 1.234E12:
The rules of printing doubles can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) (see the `toString` section). It describes exactly when the numbers will switch to scientific notation when printed.

You can also look into `NumberFormat`.