# How to display number with all decimal (not Science notation) android?

Tags: android, math, decimal

How can I show the full number instead of the scientific number when you perfonm a division this long.

```
9.34429093014885 / 10000000
```

I want to display:

```
0.000000034429093014885
```

But it keep returning:

```
9.34429093014885E-7
```

JAVA

```
 Double value = ( price / exponent);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535682/show-normal-number-instead-of-exponential-form

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal.valueOf(9.34429093014885 / 10000000).toPlainString()`

Gives your expected result